# What is a good resource for a more intuitive/flexible understanding of optimization

Tags: derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative

Take the following example of optimization:
$$cost = 10*x + 20*y$$
Where x = cans of soup, y = cans of juice

It is easy to see in this scenario what we need to do in order to minimize cost. Just reduce the biggest partial derivative, in this case y.

However, that is the limits of my mathematical powers. I cannot change the equation to account for cost sensitivity - e.g. prioritize juice over soup by a factor of 2x or something.

This problem becomes even more significant w/ larger more interesting problems/equations.

My question is how do I get a more intuitive understanding, learn how to better manipulate derivatives/gradients/gradient descent in order to suit my needs. Is there a study that is focused on this? A textbook maybe? A specific chapter?

Comment: Not sure if this fits your needs but I would recommend to search around the keywords "linear programming" and "simplex algorithm". Apart from G**gle, you may start with the usual suspects Wikipedia and Wolfram Mathworld (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearProgramming.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your problem is always linear. What you are looking for is dual and sensitivity of the linear program.

Chapter 5 and 6 of [Linear and Non Linear Optimization](https://books.google.com/books/about/Linear_and_Nonlinear_Optimization.html?id=u63u_iNcnRkC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en#v=onepage&q&f=false) have exactly what you want.